# How to add custom controller without adding additional layer in google map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am using a google map API in my web page.I have added custom text box on the map on BOTTOM_LEFT side.After that I gave `margin-left: 40px;`
Now I can't change the map by hand icon on those 40px; area.
How can I fix this?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you give an example, what do you mean you can 't change the map, you can't move it over there? Please post a fiddle

Answer (score 1):

I ve made an example and everything works perfectly (If I understood you correctly when you applied margin-left:40px; you couldn't get the "hand" cursor showing).

JS:

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(45.397, 25.644);
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);


    function textBox() {
        var searchTextBox = $('<input type="text" id="txtGeoSearch" />');
        var div = $('<div class="searchbox"></div>')
            .append($('<span>Search:</span>'))
            .append(searchTextBox);

        return div.get(0);
    }
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT].push(new textBox());
```

CSS:

```
#map_canvas {
    width:500px;
    height:300px
}
.searchbox {
    border:2px solid blue;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:40px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:500px; height:300px"></div>
```

and here is the fiddle, URL: http://jsfiddle.net/cFpkt/505/

Comment: Yes my issue is that.but for me hand cursor not working properly.I will put my code.